# Sass-компилятор не обрабатывает background: url()

Tags: css3, visual-studio-code, sass

Всем добрый вечер.Подскажите,поставил SASS
Но компилируются все свойства кроме `Background: Url`
Отказывается обрабатывать
В чем может быть проблема?
Заранее благодарю за ответ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где вы прочитали о такой записи как `(center / cover)` (218 строка у вас)?

Comment: Уроки Udemy.Смотрел там

Comment: нигде не встречал такую запись.. Попробуйте воспользоваться обычной записью `background: url() no-repeat center center / cover;`

Comment: Так дело не в записи в SASS.Мне вообще не дает применить данное свойство
Он просто не обрабатывает его 
Отображает URL не ценность свойства,а просто слово

Comment: Увы, пытался воспроизвести ваш код, но с такой проблемой столкнуться не смог ([скрин](https://i.imgur.com/Y7pBFSO.png)). Посмотрите что выводит консоль

Comment: Подскажите что за программа? Попробую там

Comment: Не совсем программа, сайт - [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/), там во вкладке **CSS** поменяйте CSS на SASS - [скрин](https://i.imgur.com/4NOe1JS.png)

Comment: Решил проблему) Снес VSC а также конфиг.Переустановил и все работает) 
Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Было бы неплохо переименовать вопрос во что-нибудь подобное: "Sass-компилятор не обрабатывает background: url()"